# Where should number_format (logic relating to the view) go un CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

After discussing with a colleague, we are mixed in where we think logic relating to the view should go.

For example lets say we have a number that we want to show in our view. I think the `number_format` (or `CakeNumber::format` as we're using CakePHP) should go in the view as it's related to what we show. My colleague thinks it should go in the controller because that's where all logic goes.

In this case we have two views, one for the website and end users and an API view which returns a json response. If I were to put the code in the controller I'd have to check which view I'm using as not to give a string in the json response when really it is an integer. For this reason I'm heavily supporting the code in the view.

The question is, who is "more" right, where should that number formatting go?

Further to my argument of putting code in the view, he is happy to use `htmlentities` in the view but I argue that if I'm not allowed number_format, he can't have `htmlentities` and that it should be done in the controller.

Comment: I my opinion, you are right. That should go in the view since it is only used for formatting purposes (just as `htmlentities`) and does nothing with the business logic of the application.

Comment: Imho, Controller definitly, the view has to do the least operations

Comment: @Answers_Seeker IMO, controllers should be kept as thin as possible.

Comment: Where did you get that "Controller is where logic all logic go" ?

Comment: Not from the documentation because it explains the opposite http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html "The Model layer represents the part of your application that implements the business logic."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the rules of MVC all logic should go in the model, not the controller The controller should only pull everything the view needs together, then hand it off to the view to be displayed.

That having been said in my experience the View often ends up with small parts of logic in it. Converting the formatting a number or escaping content with htmlentities is all very minor stuff in the end and is fine to be in the view, some people would even consider using those functions as formatting rather than business logic. Lots of people, myself included, refer to small functions such as these as *helpers* (as pointed out by Armage in the comments) and using them in views is common and definitely accepted .

This is of course all my opinion formed from years trying to keep content separate and in the right place, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Ok with that. "helpers" are often used to add specific (view-oriented) logic in View layer.

Comment: `all logic should go in the model, not the controller` Leaving aside the mythical rules of MVC (there are multiple interpretations of what MVC means, Cake's is arguably closer to MVP) in CakePHP _presentational_ logic such as escaping html entities _does not_ go in the model.

Comment: Please note: from the edit history this answer changed its mind from where presentation logic should be, suggestion he was swayed by other answers and was accepted based on others’ opinion rather than the author's own.

Comment: @MartinBean Every version of the answer has said having presentation login in the view is acceptable. I may have changed the wording a bit when Armage posted about helpers but I always said small parts of logic end up in the view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31142032/revisions: Revision 1: “According to the rules of MVC all logic should go in the **controller**”. Revision 2: “According to the rules of MVC all logic should go in the **model**”. You _completely_ changed the basis of your answer after others were adding in what appears to be an attempt to save face.

Comment: @MartinBean I rushed my answer and got a basic fact wrong because the OP posted that all logic goes in the controller. Once I'd seen another answer saying that all logic goes in the model I realised the mistake I made and corrected it. That's what edit is for. It **does not** mean I *completely* changed the basis of my answer to save face. It means I realised my mistake and corrected it. Stop being an ass.

Comment: I’m not being an ass. Just merely pointing out a fundamental part of this answer changed.

Comment: @MartinBean Great, do you go around every question that's been changed pointing out errors that have been corrected?

Comment: No. Just the ones I notice change their narrative after others add their answers. And you’re the first.

Comment: @MartinBean So, you're being an ass. What does it matter that I corrected an error? Why do you feel the need to point that out?

Answer (score 5):

> For example lets say we have a number that we want to show in our view. I think the number_format (or CakeNumber::format as we're using CakePHP) should go in the view as it's related to what we show. My colleague thinks it should go in the controller because that's where all logic goes.

Your buddy is wrong. You should use the [NumberHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/number.html) in fact which is a wrapper around the static CakeNumber. You usually want to avoid statics and singletons in your app, also a helper can be aliased, so use the NumberHelper in the views. The view is the right place.

> In this case we have two views, one for the website and end users and an API view which returns a json response. If I were to put the code in the controller I'd have to check which view I'm using as not to give a string in the json response when really it is an integer. For this reason I'm heavily supporting the code in the view.

The controller doesn't need to have a single line changed to support json and other output. Well, you *can* use the built in serialization of the view vars to json/xml OR build custom json views. [Read this chapter.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) However, there is no need to create two methods or fill the controller with business logic which is in fact wrong.

> The question is, who is "more" right, where should that number formatting go?

Definitely the view.

A controller should be skinny and not contain any business logic:

[image]

> Further to my argument of putting code in the view, he is happy to use htmlentities in the view but I argue that if I'm not allowed number_format, he can't have htmlentities and that it should be done in the controller.

Use [h()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/function-h.html) which is a shortcut for htmlspecialchars(). And make sure you use it for *everything* you echo there. All the core helpers that come with the framework will do that internally for you if you pass something through them but pay attention to third party helpers that might not use it!

Answer (score 1):

> My colleague things it should go in the controller because that's where all logic goes.

**No business logic goes into the controller.** That's not MVC. It's an atrocity.

In cases like this, always imagine a scenario that MVC was primarily designed for: swap out your controller/view for an alternative interface. For example, imagine writing a command line client for your app, e.g. to do administrative backend tasks. You'll want to be able to do **the same things** on the command line as your users can do on the website, for example:

```
$ admin users create Bob bob@example.com
```

This does the same thing in the model that a regular user registration on the website would do, but it requires a different controller (one that can handle CLI interaction) and a different view (one which just outputs plain text). Since you obviously do not want to repeat any business logic while writing this, **no businesses logic goes into the controller**. It must all be in the model.

And formatting numbers is obviously a responsibility of the view, because it's a visual, human-readable concern.

Comment: "Cake is very often promoting the terrible practice of stuffing your controller full of code"  Care to elaborate?

Comment: I thought I did. Stuffing controllers full of business logic is plain wrong for the reasons mentioned above. A controller is a bit of glue between the model/view and the real world. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *none* of the official documentation promotes this. In fact many people do it wrong but this is clearly **not** promoted by the framework. The only thing I would agree with is that it lacks a service layer.

Comment: @burzum I'll admit to not having touched Cake in forever, but it was always structured around the model being a thin abstraction around database tables, and the controller calling `$this->model->find()` and `->save()` in its various flavours. That alone is already too much database-layer expose to the controller for my taste. I don't know if things have dramatically improved recently, but most users apparently haven't gotten the message yet.

Comment: If you haven't touched CakePHP "in forever" then why taking the time to say "CakePHP promotes the terrible practice of stuffing your controller full of code"?

Comment: @deceze If you haven't touched it much please refrain from making **false** statements about it or provide some proof. In fact at least the 2.x documentation *clearly* states the opposite of your statement: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html First sentence there about the model: "The Model layer represents the part of your application that implements the business logic."

Comment: `it was always structured around the model being a thin abstraction around database tables` I think this is the fundamental misconception (that's never been true, but it _is_ how beginners write their code putting way too much code in controllers, and not restricted to CakePHP-only either). +1 as currently written.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s for manipulating how data is presented, then it should sit in a layer between the controller and the view. Your controller should fetch data from models, and your view should display that data. Your view could be anything: HTML, PDF, CSV, JSON etc.

Have a look at view presenters. They take an entity and prepares its data for presenting in a view. Therefore, your view presenter class could have a method called `priceFormatted()` that returns the price value formatting with decimal places, thousands separator, currency symbols etc. This way, you could use your presenter methods in your HTML view, but for other views (i.e. XML or JSON) you could just use the raw value.

Comment: An example of view presenters would probably help the reader. [Something like this](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/dc17c2e1f7d7c14ecbd4).